# ionic push notification not working after changed the apple id

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, ionic-cloud

***Please note this:***

### [This question is no longer valid, because of ionic push notification has been shutdown now.](https://blog.ionicframework.com/sunsetting-ionic-cloud-push-and-auth/)

> As of February 1, 2018, we will no longer provide Push and Auth
>   services. Anyone with an existing Cloud account can continue using
>   Push and Auth through January 2018. After that, you’ll need to find an
>   alternative provider.
>
> The Ionic community is already using a number of leading push and auth
>   providers today.
>
> For Push notifications, we recommend [AWS Pinpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/) ,
>   [OneSignal](https://onesignal.com/), and [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), based on their overall popularity
>   and the number of helpful tutorials and docs that should make it easy
>   for you to get set up. Additionally, OneSignal has created a landing
>   page [specifically for Ionic Push developers](https://onesignal.com/ionic).

<kbd>[Find more here...](https://blog.ionicframework.com/sunsetting-ionic-cloud-push-and-auth/)</kbd>

ionic push notification not working after changed the apple id

I am using ionic push notification service.
I created a ios app and integrated push notification with it and working well.
I changed my apple developer account agent roll to another apple id. 
Previously used apple id developer account has been expired and recently renew it to 
new apple id after informed it to apple developer support.
Now previously used iOS Provisioning profile has been invalidated and 
new provisioning profile has been created under new apple id.
I created a new build of iOS app and test the push notifications. Now it is not 
working on new app (cannot send push notification but device is registered with token)
 and old app still working well. It is in a app store now (old app).

If I remove my previous build credentials from ionic push security profile 
and if I create them again with new details, will new app get work with push notification? 
will it effect to the already working app in production or 
will it work even? Here I am using production configuration for the new app also.
Do I need to create new iOS push certification also?

I need to get work both app's push notification in production. I did not changed the build credentials from ionic push security profile yet because I need to things get cleared before do that from some one who have experienced with this kind of matter before.

NOTE: I did not create new bundle id. Same bundle id is using.

Greatly  appreciate any kind of your help on this matter.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You would need to create new push notification certificate in your new account and get that new pem file to the server as long as old pem file is in server your push will work in App Store build so in simpler word you will have to find a way to use 2 pem file by maybe keeping same old structure for existing and for new you have to create a work around so you are able to store the pem file in separate place so push works in both places.

Comment: thanks. the thing is i am using ionic cloud push notification service. i don't know how they handle pem files in their server. i could create new one but still hesitate about the old application push notification.

Comment: I am a native developer so gave my knowledge as per native. I think you should check iconic forum. All the best

Answer (score 1):

Apple sending push notification by bundle(com.testcompany.testApp), so if you create new bundle(new app) you must register it and repeat all configurations for it, because Apple recognize it as a new app.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. I did not create a new bundle, same bundle id but i only changed the apple id.

Comment: ok, can you check, in your developer account App IDs , is it same as in previous version ? maybe you create new push certificate ?

Comment: yes. App IDs are same. I did not create new push certification yet using previous one still

Comment: Ok, you must create a new one, because your provisioning profile is generated with app id, create it and regenerate and add it to server to send push notification with new push certificate

Comment: ok. i could do that. then old application push notification will work as usual?

Comment: no, to handle that you must add 2 push certificates to send 2 push notification on server every time , to old and new apps

Comment: i am using ionic cloud push notification, are they handle this kind of situation i have no idea about that. they have a option to upload .p12 file but have to remove previous one. they do not have option to add two .p12 file. :(

Comment: so if you want to support 2 apps, you must configure another app in ionic, i think sending 2 push notifications for one app is not good practice at all.

Comment: no. i have one app. new app mean latest version of old app. example old app version 1.2  and new version 1.3 like that.

Comment: I just mean that sending 2 push notification from server is bad idea, just configure another app in ionic , it will be more clear and simple

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new certificates, The old certificate works as usual till you replace your .p12 file in your server.